# How to parse a json column embedded in a pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe [(raw csv file here)](http://pastebin.com/XBwJ4tBq) which contains a couple of columns stored as json (d1 & d2). How do I parse these columns to give me the required output of:

**2015-02-12,user1,05:15 | 20,16:30 | 20.0,22:00 | 10.0**

I realise I have to transpose the output once successfully parsed,but I'm having problems in reading the json data contained in the dataframe column. Any help appreciated! Thanks

```
>>> test = pd.read_csv('schedsample.csv',sep=',', header=0)
>>> test.head()
         date username                                                 d1  \
0  2015-02-12    user1  {"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30"...   
1  2015-02-12    user1  {"d2":[{"tm":"06:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"08:00"...   
2  2015-02-12    user1  {"d3":[{"tm":"07:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"09:00"...   
3  2015-02-12    user1  {"d4":[{"tm":"08:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"07:00"...   

                                                  d2  
0  {"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30"...  
1  {"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30"...  
2  {"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30"...  
3  {"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30"...  
>>> import json as js
>>> js.loads(test['d1'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/khurampervez/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/khurampervez/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`
```

Comment: Because of the string representation, I can't casually copy your data to play with. Try `test.to_dict()` instead, and see if it copies the whole json entry?

Comment: @cphlewis I've tried that and it copies the whole json entry, i.e. see below `>>> d1=sched['d1'].to_dict()
>>> d1
{0: '{"d1":[{"tm":"05:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"16:30","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"22:00","t":"10.0"}]}', 1: '{"d2":[{"tm":"06:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"08:00","t":"10.0"},{"tm":"22:00","t":"10.0"}]}', 2: '{"d3":[{"tm":"07:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"09:00","t":"10.0"},{"tm":"22:00","t":"10.0"}]}', 3: '{"d4":[{"tm":"08:15","t":"20.0"},{"tm":"07:00","t":"10.0"},{"tm":"22:00","t":"10.0"}]}'}`

Comment: @cphlewis however trying to to run the json.loads command gives the below `>>> json.loads(sched['d1'].to_dict())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/khurampervez/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/khurampervez/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Answer (score 0):

Your test.d1 column contains all d1 to d4 object, so if you do `json.loads(test['d1'])` will result in errors, but if you do `json_normalize(json.loads(test['d1'][0])['d1'])`, it will give you the desired d1 dataframe. So I guess instead of read into only d1 and d2 columns, you need d3 and d4 columns as well, which will produce some empty cells.